# BibTeX: Refer to page numbers or sections

Tags: bibtex, back-referencing

I am using BibTeX for the first time and I wonder what is the correct way of referring to page numbers etc. inside a referenced book/article/website/…

Let's start with this block of code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
  For a recap on irrational numbers, see \cite{hardywright2008}.

  \bibliography{ref}
  \bibliographystyle{alpha}
\end{document}
```

I saved it in the file `mwe.tex`. Also, I have the file `ref.bib` in the same directory:

```
@book{hardywright2008,
  author = {G. H. Hardy, E. M. Wright},
  title = {An Introduction to the Theory of Numbers},
  publisher = {Oxford University Press},
  year = {2008},
  edition = {6}
}
```

When I compile using

```
pdflatex mwe.tex
bibtex mwe.aux
pdflatex mwe.tex
pdflatex mwe.tex
```

then the result looks like this:

[image: How the output from mwe.tex looks]

This is all good up to this point. But I don't want the reader to search their way through 600 pages of number theory when all they have to read is chapter 4 which starts on page 45. So I wanted to make use of the optional argument of `\cite`.
The file `mwe2.tex` contains the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
  For a recap on irrational numbers, see \cite[45]{hardywright2008}.

  \bibliography{ref}
  \bibliographystyle{alpha}
\end{document}
```

The file `ref.bib` remained unchanged. Compiling with

```
pdflatex mwe2.tex
bibtex mwe2.aux
pdflatex mwe2.tex
pdflatex mwe2.tex
```

produces this:

[image: How the output from mwe2.tex looks]

The problem is that no one will know what this number 45 means. So the reference should somehow contain the information "page 45 ff."
One way could be to omit the page-number-reference in the `\cite`-command and include it in the text that I write, like

```
For a recap on irrational numbers, see pages 45 ff. in \cite{hardywright2008}.
```

Better (in my opinion, but you may convince me that my opinion is wrong) would be to include the page-number-reference in the `\cite`-command. I could do

```
For a recap on irrational numbers, see \cite[pp. 45 ff.]{hardywright2008}.
```

Yet I don't know if the produced output is easily readable.

Is there a standard way to include references to page numbers or sections or the like in the `\cite`-command?

Comment: Hm, this question seems to be too long for such a simple question. I apologize.

Comment: Well, the short answer is probably: No, there is no standard way of doing this. The way pages are referenced (if at all) is highly specific to a journal, discipline, or author. The way you cite the pages in your last bit of code, i.e. `\cite[pp. 45 ff.]{hardywright2008}` is (as far as I'm concerned) a very common way to do it. The most important thing however is (as with all aspects of academic writing) to decide on one way of doing it and the using this method consistently throughout your document.

Comment: Other than that you are probably better of, aksing this type of question in a stackexchange dedicated to academic writing and typesetting and refer to the TeX.SE only for implementation of your method of choice (in case you run into issues doing it yourself).

Comment: On a side note: If you can choose freely, e.g. in your PhD thesis: Don't use BibTeX, use BibLaTeX or Biber. Both of which are much more modern and versatile.

Comment: Off-topic: The keyword to separate authors in the `author` field is `and`; commas have a very different function in the `author` field. Hence, you should replace `author = {G. H. Hardy, E. M. Wright},` with `author = {G. H. Hardy and E. M. Wright},`. As a result, the citation callout will also change from `GHH08`, which looks rather odd, to `HW08`, which is indeed what one would expect the citation callout to look like.

Comment: The instruction `\cite[pp. 45 ff.]{hardywright2008}` is an entirely standard way for handling the issue you are confronting.

Comment: Hi you two, and thanks for the responses.
@MarkusG.Thanks for the hint with BibLaTeX instead of BibTeX. I guess that up to this point, all I have to change is the compile command `bibtex` and use `biblatex` instead?
@Mico Ah, I was already wondering about the separation of two authors. Thank you for your hint.

Comment: @NerdOnTour - In case you haven't already done so, do check out the posting [What to do to switch to biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5091/5001).